# Referring to animal sounds and such by meaning rather than sound?

Tags: phrase-requests, animals

Is there a word/phrase/such for referring to the noises of animals while categorizing them by meaning, rather than what they sound like? The words shouldn't refer to the sound at all. Preferably it should be something that clearly distinguishs the animal sound from spoken language: Stuff like "The dog pleaded for help" isn't good for what I want because that phrase is more often used for talking

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140577/discussion-on-question-by-ichthys-king-referring-to-animal-sounds-and-such-by-me).

Answer (score 1):

An instance of animal communication is referred to as a **signal** (or *signaling*).

There are various modalities: visual, **acoustic**, chemical, tactile, and electrical signaling.

So animal sounds would be **acoustic signals** (falling under *acoustic communication*).

=================================================================

Gillam, Erin. "An Introduction to Animal Communication." [[nature.com]](https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/an-introduction-to-animal-communication-23648715/)